# Chance Javascript Function-Append into Display:none or Display:block

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am trying to make a small change to our cookie consent banner. The current script checks if a certain cookie is set to "True" or not. If not, it shows the HTML at the end of the script (which is our banner). Once the "accept" button is clicked, the cookie is set to "True" and the banner won't be shown.

However, we want to add a small form where somebody can enter their e-mailaddress, so they can let us know that they want to be removed from any tracking. But, the form seems to break it.
So we thought it would be much easier if the Javascript simply tells to show a DIV with a certain class, or to hide it (depending on wether the cookie is set to True or not).

My Javascript-knowledge to achieve this is not good enough to know how to do this.

```js
function consentOk() {
  console.log('Ok ik heb toestemming gegeven');
  //zet cookie waarin de consent is gegeven
  var cookieName = "CookieClick";
  var cookieValue = "True";
  var cookiePath = "/";
  var expirationTime = 3600; //1 uur in seconden
  expirationTime = expirationTime * 1000;
  var date = new Date();
  var dateTimeNow = date.getTime();
  date.setTime(dateTimeNow + expirationTime);
  var expirationTime = date.toUTCString();
  document.cookie = cookieName + "=" + cookieValue + "; expires=" + expirationTime + "; path=" + cookiePath;
  console.log('Ok, cookie is gezet');

  //pagina herladen, maar nu met marketingcookies
  location.reload();
}


$(document).ready(function() {
  //console.log('Waarde van de cookie is nu' + {{ CookieClick }});
  var CookieClickValue = 'False'; //{{ CookieClick }};
  if (CookieClickValue != "True") {
    showConsentBar();
  }
});

function showConsentBar() {
  $("body").append('<div id="nb-popup" class="cookie-popup"><div id="overlay"><div id="imagecontainer"><summary><div style="width: 400px;height:auto;background-color:#fff;border-radius: 25px;"><div id="sluiten" onclick="clickEffect()">Accepteer cookies</div><table><thead style="background-color: unset;">  <tr style="background-color:unset;"><th colspan="2" style="padding: 20px 20px 5px 20px;"><img src="/-/media/platform/2023/nieuw-logo/homepage/logo-2023-45px.ashx?h=45&amp;w=144&amp;la=nl-NL&amp;hash=057002C2D42204543798A3F9E2027A4F" alt=""></th><th></th></tr></thead><tbody><tr style="background-color:#fff;"><td colspan="3" style="padding: 20px 20px 5px 20px;"><h2>Accepteer onze cookies...</h2><form action="/formbuilder?fxb.FormItemId=6f66254c-ed96-4362-8ab5-12e22aadaabb&amp;fxb.HtmlPrefix=fxb.b36ac145-8391-4a26-b283-c5bf619853b3" data-ajax="true" data-ajax-method="Post" data-ajax-mode="replace-with" data-ajax-success="$.validator.unobtrusive.parse("#fxb_b36ac145-8391-4a26-b283-c5bf619853b3_6f66254c-ed96-4362-8ab5-12e22aadaabb");$.fxbFormTracker.texts=$.fxbFormTracker.texts||{};$.fxbFormTracker.texts.expiredWebSession="Your session has expired. Please refresh this page.";$.fxbFormTracker.parse("#fxb_b36ac145-8391-4a26-b283-c5bf619853b3_6f66254c-ed96-4362-8ab5-12e22aadaabb");$.fxbConditions.parse("#fxb_b36ac145-8391-4a26-b283-c5bf619853b3_6f66254c-ed96-4362-8ab5-12e22aadaabb")" data-ajax-update="#fxb_b36ac145-8391-4a26-b283-c5bf619853b3_6f66254c-ed96-4362-8ab5-12e22aadaabb" data-sc-fxb="6f66254c-ed96-4362-8ab5-12e22aadaabb" enctype="multipart/form-data" id="fxb_b36ac145-8391-4a26-b283-c5bf619853b3_6f66254c-ed96-4362-8ab5-12e22aadaabb" method="post"><input id="fxb_b36ac145-8391-4a26-b283-c5bf619853b3_FormSessionId" name="fxb.b36ac145-8391-4a26-b283-c5bf619853b3.FormSessionId" type="hidden" value="a301fbc5-73d6-4b76-80b8-da7a50472345"><input id="fxb_b36ac145-8391-4a26-b283-c5bf619853b3_IsNewSession" name="fxb.b36ac145-8391-4a26-b283-c5bf619853b3.IsNewSession" type="hidden" value="1"><input name="__RequestVerificationToken" type="hidden" value="BLzWp_x6T9RGm85LYQQdd8VLdErYRy1TYGpJj0SKiQ6cVRUsZ2xbNj99xwCxb-Ak-wJu9X3UWF_UbYaq79XRFg-SHc6iivvXNpsHD0MPW_k1"><input id="fxb_b36ac145-8391-4a26-b283-c5bf619853b3_FormItemId" name="fxb.b36ac145-8391-4a26-b283-c5bf619853b3.FormItemId" type="hidden" value="6f66254c-ed96-4362-8ab5-12e22aadaabb"><input id="fxb_b36ac145-8391-4a26-b283-c5bf619853b3_PageItemId" name="fxb.b36ac145-8391-4a26-b283-c5bf619853b3.PageItemId" type="hidden" value="9ce27668-a652-43cb-b046-abc744c8555b"><input id="fxb_b36ac145-8391-4a26-b283-c5bf619853b3_Fields_Index_617b90b5-5ffe-4e2d-9bff-88c022c1a2a6" name="fxb.b36ac145-8391-4a26-b283-c5bf619853b3.Fields.Index" type="hidden" value="617b90b5-5ffe-4e2d-9bff-88c022c1a2a6"><input id="fxb_b36ac145-8391-4a26-b283-c5bf619853b3_Fields_617b90b5-5ffe-4e2d-9bff-88c022c1a2a6__ItemId" name="fxb.b36ac145-8391-4a26-b283-c5bf619853b3.Fields[617b90b5-5ffe-4e2d-9bff-88c022c1a2a6].ItemId" type="hidden" value="617b90b5-5ffe-4e2d-9bff-88c022c1a2a6"><label for="fxb_b36ac145-8391-4a26-b283-c5bf619853b3_Fields_617b90b5-5ffe-4e2d-9bff-88c022c1a2a6__Value" class=""></label><input id="fxb_b36ac145-8391-4a26-b283-c5bf619853b3_Fields_617b90b5-5ffe-4e2d-9bff-88c022c1a2a6__Value" name="fxb.b36ac145-8391-4a26-b283-c5bf619853b3.Fields[617b90b5-5ffe-4e2d-9bff-88c022c1a2a6].Value" class="" type="email" value="Jouw e-mailadres" maxlength="255" placeholder="" data-sc-tracking="True" data-sc-field-name="Email" data-sc-field-key="2D91EC95798142C2B8944AAF1A9FB9C5" data-val-required=" is required." data-val-regex="" data-val-regex-pattern="^[A-Za-z0-9._%+-]+@[A-Za-z0-9.-]+\.[A-Za-z]{2,17}$" data-val="true"><span class="field-validation-valid" data-valmsg-for="fxb.b36ac145-8391-4a26-b283-c5bf619853b3.Fields[617b90b5-5ffe-4e2d-9bff-88c022c1a2a6].Value" data-valmsg-replace="true"></span><input value="Ik maak bezwaar en wil verwijderd worden" type="submit" class="" name="fxb.b36ac145-8391-4a26-b283-c5bf619853b3.4a33c329-1e49-4950-bf91-c8c46307e4f2" data-sc-field-key="186725BF4E9D43FB8173CE2291022E41"><input id="fxb_b36ac145-8391-4a26-b283-c5bf619853b3_NavigationButtons" name="fxb.b36ac145-8391-4a26-b283-c5bf619853b3.NavigationButtons" type="hidden" value="4a33c329-1e49-4950-bf91-c8c46307e4f2"><input id="fxb_b36ac145-8391-4a26-b283-c5bf619853b3_4a33c329-1e49-4950-bf91-c8c46307e4f2" name="fxb.b36ac145-8391-4a26-b283-c5bf619853b3.4a33c329-1e49-4950-bf91-c8c46307e4f2" type="hidden" value="0"><input type="hidden" data-sc-fxb-condition="" value="{}"></form></tbody></table></div></summary></div></div></div>');
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Basically, the first DIV with class cookie-popup (or ID nb-popup) should simply get a "display:none;" or "display:block;" depending on the value of the cookie.
In my code above, you see that the whole HTML code is inside the Javascript. But we would like to end the javascript with something like this (not proper coding, I know):

```
  function showConsentBar() {
    $(div.cookie-popup).setCss('display:block;'); }
```

The general idea is that the Javascript adds the CSS "display:block;" when the cookie is set to False (or is empty). This should cause the DIV to show up.
If the cookie is set to "True", the DIV should get "Display:none;" and not be shown.

Disclaimer: I am aware that the cookie lifetime is very short. We only used this number for testing purposes. We will increase to a much higher number in the live version.
Also: the form is generated by a CMS. I've tried to make it smaller and simpler, but the CMS won't accept the input and give an error. This is wy it's quite long for such a simply form.

Comment: `$('#nb-popup').toggle(/*true or false, depending on what your cookie value indicates*/);` - https://api.jquery.com/toggle/

Comment: I've tried to change it to:  `function showConsentBar() {$('#nb-popup').toggle(False); } 
 ` `
And replaced the HTML outside of the Javascript. But now it always shows. Even when clicked on  "Consent" it will still show the banner after the reload.

Comment: `False` is not the same as `false`. And why a hard-coded value in the first place, when you said you wanted to make this dependent on the cookie value?

Comment: What you are doing in the document ready handler there, also makes little sense. `if (CookieClickValue != "True")` - that can not ever _not_ be true, when you assign  `var CookieClickValue = 'False';` directly before it.

Comment: I have not written the Javascript code, I'm only trying to achieve something with something that was written a while ago.  This is probably also the reason why I "hardcoded" something I shouldn't have done.
I am not completely sure how to use your first answer in a way that works for me.

Comment: It looks like the whole thing _was_ already prepared to do what you want. `showConsentBar` only gets called, `if (CookieClickValue != "True")`. And it looks like originally, `CookieClickValue` got its value from a template variable `{{ CookieClick }}`- but someone replaced that with a hardcoded `False`. _Does_ this template variable give you the correct cookie status? If so, then you should not need to do anything more, than revert that change. `var CookieClickValue = {{ CookieClick }};`

Comment: I've also just noticed that somebody has edited my original code. Not sure why, but the original code uses a Tag Manager variable {{CookieClick}} which is either "undefined" or "True". So I can understand the confusion seeing as somebody has been editing my original code.